Proof that all the solutions of $f'(x)=g(x)f(x)$ have the form $f(x)=ax$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$
Let $f$, $g$ be functions from an interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is differentiable, $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in I$, and
$$ f'(x)=g(x)f(x) $$
Then what are the solutions of this equation? I know that $f(x)=ax$, $a\in\mathbb{R}^*$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, are solutions; however I need to show that those are the only solutions. Is this provable or is there a counterexample?
This specific problem comes form a real analysis problem

Let $\lambda : I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ a differentiable path such that $\lambda(t)\neq 0$ and $\lambda '(t)=f(t)\lambda(t)$ for every $t\in I$. Proof that the image $\lambda (I)$ is contained in a line that crosses the origin.

This question is pretty much solved if I can somehow show that my conjecture is true.
Thanks in advance, all comments are appreciated.

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=g(x)$$ Integrating both sides gives $\ln|f(x)|=G(x)+C,$ where $G'(x)=g(x),$ giving $$f(x)=C'e^{G(x)}.$$

Unfortunately, the conjecture is not true. For example, we can also take $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = 1$. More generally, the differential equation says the derivative of the log of $f(x)$ is $g(x)$, so for a broad class of $g(x)$ you can just pick an antiderivative and exponentiate it to get a choice of $f(x)$.

Very much appreciated. Interestingly, this also solves the original problem with $\lambda$ and $f$. If $\lambda_i(t)=k_i e^{F(t)}$, where $F(t)$ is the primitive of $f(t)$ (it can be shown that $f$ is continuous), then the path would be $\lambda(t)=(k_1 e^{F(t)},...,k_ne^{F(t)})$ which has the form of $(k_1x,...,k_nx)$ that lies in the line $t(k_1,...,k_n)$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$ that crosses the origin!

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=g(x)$$ Integrating both sides gives $\ln|f(x)|=G(x)+C,$ where $G'(x)=g(x),$ giving $$f(x)=C'e^{G(x)}.$$
So given any differentiable $G$ and constant $C$ there is a solution $f(x)=e^{G(x)}, g(x)=G'(x).$
